# Laravel 8: Recuperar dados Usuário Logado

Tags: laravel

Ola,

eu não uso uma tabela padrão de usuários sugerida no Laravel, pois eu estou criando um frontend em um banco de dados já existe.

Todo o processo do login está funcionando corretamente, com verificação de usuário de senha. Mas o meu problema é que quando ele chama o menu eu não consigo recuperar os dados do usuário que foi logado no sistema. No menu quando eu coloco `dd(auth()->user())` ele retorna null.

Queria saber o que falta no meu código para eu conseguir recuperar os dados do login do usuário.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Repositories\UserRepository;
use App\Validators\UserValidator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Exception;
Use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    private $repository;
    private $validator;

    public function __construct(UserRepository $repository, UserValidator $validator)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
        $this->validator  = $validator;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('user.dashboard');
    }

    public function auth(Request $request)
    {
        
        $data = [
            'U_NAME'    => $request->get('username'),
            'PASSWORD4' => $request->get('password')
        ];
        try
        {
            if(env('PASSWORD_HASH'))
            {
                Auth::attempt($data, false);
            }
            else
            {
                DB::enableQueryLog();
                $user = $this->repository->findwhere(['USER_CODE' => $request->get('username')])->first();
                if(!$user)
                {
                    return redirect()->route('user.login')->withErrors(['Usuário Inválido']);
                }
                if((trim($user->PASSWORD4)) != (trim($request->get('password'))))
                {
                    return redirect()->route('user.login')->withErrors(['Senha Incorreta']);
                }
                Auth::login($user);
            }
            return redirect()->route('user.dashboard');
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Como você configurou a classe de usuários personalizadas, só com o parte do Login fica complicado saber!

Answer (score 0):

Eu consegui resolver fazendo colocando as informações na session, abaixo a nova classe com a alteração

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Repositories\UserRepository;
use App\Validators\UserValidator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Exception;
Use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    private $repository;
    private $validator;

    public function __construct(UserRepository $repository, UserValidator $validator)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
        $this->validator  = $validator;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('user.dashboard');
    }

    public function auth(Request $request)
    {
        $data = [
            'U_NAME'    => $request->get('username'),
            'PASSWORD4' => $request->get('password')
        ];
        try
        {
            if(env('PASSWORD_HASH'))
            {
                Auth::attempt($data, false);
            }
            else
            {
                DB::enableQueryLog();
                $user = $this->repository->findwhere(['USER_CODE' => $request->get('username')])->first();
                if(!$user)
                {
                    return redirect()->route('user.login')->withErrors(['Usuário Inválido']);
                }
                if((trim($user->PASSWORD4)) != (trim($request->get('password'))))
                {
                    return redirect()->route('user.login')->withErrors(['Senha Incorreta']);
                }
                Auth::login($user);
            }
                $request->session()->put('USER_CODE', $user->USER_CODE);
                $request->session()->put('U_NAME',    $user->U_NAME);
                $request->session()->put('SUPERUSER', $user->SUPERUSER);
                return redirect()->route('user.dashboard');
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```